# matching several combinations of columns in a table

Tags: numpy

I am reading a table where all its values has to be validated before we process it further. The valid values are stored in another table that we match our main table with. The validation criteria is to match several columns as follows:

```
Table 1 (the main data we read in)

Name --- Unit --- Age --- Address --- Nationality
```

The above shows the column names that we are reading from the table and the other table contains the valid values of the above columns . When we look only for valid values in our main table, we have to consider combination of columns in the main data table, for example Name --- Unit --- Age. If all the value in a particular row for the column combination matches against the other table then we keep the row, otherwise we delete it.

How do I address the issue with Numpy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can just loop through rows. An easy/simple way would be:

```
dummy_df = table_df ## make a copy of your table, since we are deleting rows we want to have the original df saved.

relevant_columns = ['age','name','sex',...] ## define relevant columns, in case either dataframe has columns you dont want to compare on

for indx in dummy_df.index :

    ## checks if any row is identical, if so, drops it.

    if ((np.array(dummy_df.loc[indx][relevant_columns]) == main_df[relevant_columns].values).sum(1) == len(relevant_columns)).sum() > 0:

        dummy_df = dummy_df .drop(indx)
```

ps: i am assuming the data is in pandas dataframe format. 
hope it helps :)

ps2: if the headers/columns have different names it wont work